# Help with a CMS for content only not display

Tags: web-development, cms, database, recommendations, data

Hello I'm trying to make some kind of tool for an school website, what I need to do is to make students take a test and according to what are the results (27 posibilities) they get a set of activities (questions) according to their level which they can solve in around 3 months logging periodically to the website, plus I need teachers to log and look at the reports.

Now, I'm a graphic designer myself so my skills are mostly html5 and css3 and I know some php (edit existing ones only) and javascript (jquery) as well, most people tell me that I need a CMS to do the tool but all I find is CMS for display like blogs or news websites which I think aren't useful for me because the website is already made in html and css3 only (I need to add an extra page for the tool)

I understand I need to create users and give them special rights according to what type of user they are and I also understand that I need a database where I can store all my questions.

What is the best way to do this? what do you suggest me?

Thanks

Comment: Your best of taking a look at codecanyon for premade php scripts http://codecanyon.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=quiz

Comment: I think someone around my place can help me with the logical part of how to make the quiz, what I'm really looking for is a way to store the content that will be viewed by the students, I know I need a database and users but I'm not sure if a CMS can help me manage that.

Comment: you can use the cms as a wrapper just so people can log in and write the rest in php or js yourself

Comment: @user2091756 take a look at my answer, using WordPress is a great way to store the content, both tests, answers, students and teacher accounts. If you'd like help and more details drop me a line http://bit.ly/UHR2WS

Comment: tried WordPress + Sensei?

Answer (score 0):

Since CMS's comprise a huge variety of options, it sounds like what you're thinking of implementing is an educationally oriented CMS (often called LMS's), e.g. Blackboard, or Moodle.

Moodle is an open-source option specifically designed and supplemented to work for class user dynamics, and with a host of tools that may answer you problem. As a CMS, you would set this up as a sub-domain most likely to maintain your otherwise html-based site.

Your hosting provider will likely have relevant instructions on making a sub-domain or simply a directory sub to the root for you to install the LMS in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know what Moodle is, I even have one installed in my pc using Xampp apache server because we were trying different options during the last months, I'm not really sure why we discarded moodle but there was a solid reason, I'll check again my documentation. Thanks

Comment: I got the answer why we discarded moodle, idk if we can do this in moodle but the school wants the kids to take a test and according to that test the kids are set into a level, and according to that level the program gives the student a set of questions so they can improve their level, but this set is not static it should be flexible, in other words a student in a level 6 might have gotten the incorrect level so they want the tool to promote or demote the student 'on the fly' according to how their progress is going. The exact way to do this is still being developement by the teachers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use WordPress and have tests as a custom post type with questions as another custom post type related to the test custom post type.

Within the question custom posts you'll have custom fields, one field would store the correct answer to the question.

Another custom post type to store user settings, this being separate from the user object. This cpt has a custom field relating it to the user ID.

Lastly another custom post type (CPT) to store results of questions and tests, you can store test completions, and questions correct in a serialized array, or json array for easy access.

Now on the front end use a conditional that would check what tests the student has taken and passed by checking the CPT storing the test results. If they haven't taken any test display test 1's questions.

Use AJAX / jQuery to check the answers, once they've passed a test completely the conditional would display the next test or set of questions.

Teachers could have their own customized front end displaying all students, the tests they've started, completed and questions answered correctly/wrongly etc. You can store really every question answer they submit, datetime and see their progress.

It's really quite easy using WordPress, it's just a matter of figuring out the student and teacher work flow exactly to get the CPT and CF's setup.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal can help you achieve exactly this, with its inbuilt user types, permissions, content creation kit and rules module or workflow.